# Conexión SQL Server 2018 con Excel se congela

Tags: sql, excel

He realizado una conexión desde Excel hacia SQL Server 2018 de forma local sin problemas, pero al realizar alguna modificación a las tablas desde MSSQL y me dirijo a Excel este no actualiza y se queda cargando. Esto no sucede con las versión de SQL 2008 que es la única que he probado hasta el momento. Sucede con todas las versiones de Excel.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, exactamente que deseas saber? de paso te recomiendo que leas  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para hacer una buena pregunta

Comment: Realizar una conexión entre SQL Server 2018 con Excel. Inicialmente si logro realizarlo, pero al modificar la tabla y actualizar la conexión está no termina nunca de ejecutarse como muestra la imágen de arriba.

Comment: Hola DiegoOrbezo: No existe Sql Server 2018. Para saber la versión exacta de tu servidor, puedes utilizar en una ventana del management studio SELECT @@Version. Cuantas instancias tienes de Sql Server en la máquina. Con que usuario conectas (windows o sql)